# Bad performance parsing multi-status response

Tags: xml, performance, dart, webdav, caldav

I am using the xml library to parse a multi status response. The code take a lot of seconds to parse a simple xml. What can I do to improve performance? I cannot use async code in a factory.

I am amazed at the speed at which the xml library parses and without any asynchronous code. I was trying to analyze the code of the library to take it as an example of what I can do, but I can't understand it.

```
import 'package:xml/xml.dart';

class MultiStatus {
  final List<Response> response;
  final String? syncToken;

  MultiStatus({required this.response, this.syncToken});

  factory MultiStatus.fromXml(XmlDocument element) {
    var response = <Response>[];

    var multistatus = element.firstElementChild;

    if (multistatus!.name.local == 'multistatus') {
      var elements = multistatus.children.whereType<XmlElement>();

      // add responses
      elements
          .where((element) => element.name.local == 'response')
          .forEach((element) {
        response.add(Response.fromXml(element));
      });

      try {
        var syncToken = elements
            .firstWhere((element) => element.name.local == 'sync-token');

        return MultiStatus(response: response, syncToken: syncToken.text);
      } catch (e) {
        return MultiStatus(response: response);
      }
    }

    throw Error();
  }

  factory MultiStatus.fromString(String string){
    var document = XmlDocument.parse(string);

    return MultiStatus.fromXml(document);
  }
}

class Response {
  final String href;
  final Propstat propstat;

  Response({required this.href, required this.propstat});

  factory Response.fromXml(XmlElement element) {
    if (element.name.local == 'response') {
      var elements = element.children.whereType<XmlElement>();

      var href =
          elements.firstWhere((element) => element.name.local == 'href').text;

      var propstatXml =
          elements.firstWhere((element) => element.name.local == 'propstat');

      return Response(href: href, propstat: Propstat.fromXml(propstatXml));
    }

    throw Error();
  }
}

class Propstat {
  final Map<String, dynamic> prop;
  final int status;

  Propstat({required this.prop, required this.status});

  factory Propstat.fromXml(XmlElement element) {
    if (element.name.local == 'propstat') {
      var prop = <String, dynamic>{};

      var elements = element.children.whereType<XmlElement>();

      var props = elements
          .firstWhere((element) => element.name.local == 'prop')
          .children
          .whereType<XmlElement>();

      props.forEach((element) {
        var value = element.text.isNotEmpty
            ? element.text
            : element.children.whereType<XmlElement>();

        prop[element.name.local] = value;
      });

      var status = elements
          .firstWhere((element) => element.name.local == 'status')
          .text
          .split(' ')[1];

      return Propstat(prop: prop, status: int.parse(status));
    }

    throw Error();
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    var string = '';

    prop.forEach((key, value) {
      var valueString = value.toString();

      string += '$key: ${valueString.length > 200 ? '\n' : ''}$valueString';
    });

    return string;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what is wrong from the code you post.

Could you share one or more of the following details?

- a [profile](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/performance) dump of the runtime (to let me figure out where time is spent);
- provide a runnable (ideally minimal) example that includes the input data;
- if that is not possible, provide at least some quantitative information of the  input data (file size, file structure, size of different parts, number of elements; how is the data loaded; ...);
- provide information about the device/machine you run the code on;
- etc.

Comment: Thanks, it was just something that was solved by closing and reopening vs code.